# Regex for Bash Script Checking MTR

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that will grep output from the 'mtr' command and look for packet loss that is over 0.0%.  In other words, anything over 1.*% should trigger the alert.

I've been playing around with the below REGEX bash script and can't seem to get it working.  Any advice or direction is greatly appreciated!

```
PACKETLOSS="[1-9]\.[0-9]\%"
mtr -r -c 1 192.0.0.0 | grep PACKETLOSS &> /dev/null
if [ $? == PACKETLOSS ]; then
   echo "Packet loss to server 192.0.0.0!"
fi
```

Comment: Could you please also post output of `mtr -r -c 1 192.0.0.0` command in your post with CODE TAGS and let us know, it will be easier for us to guide you then.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ony mistake is your in IF statment, you have to compare the error code (if any match this code is 0).
Also you can make your regex better by adding a + after the first digit, so 10.0% to 100.0% also matches.

```
PACKETLOSS="[1-9]\+\.[0-9]\%"
mtr -r -c 1 192.0.0.0 | grep PACKETLOSS &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   echo "Packet loss to server 192.0.0.0!"
fi
```

this code works for me

Comment: I'm trying to test this with changing the variable to PACKETLOSS="[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\%", since 0.0% is the standard, and I'm not getting the echo alert statement.

Comment: I got your code working by using grep with the REGIX instead of a variable.  Not sure why it only works this way for me, but either way, it works now.  Thanks @Hans! 
Working code `mtr -r -c 1 192.0.0.0 | grep "[1-9]\+\.[0-9]\%" &> /dev/null`